# Is There a Default Time Zone ID for Every Time Zone in the U.S.?

Tags: java, timezone

I'm currently working on a project fix that needs to pull time zones, but it's no longer 3 letter abbreviations. It's America/Chicago (for me), however I need to know, and cannot seem to find the default Time Zone ID's for each Time Zone in the U.S.

Comment: Those IDs are called Olson IDs.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you mean. The time zone id for a time zone is its id. There is no simple mapping between US names and proper time zone IDs, however, because places like Phoenix switch between Mountain and Central time zones (since it doesn't observe daylight savings). That's why you need IDs like America/Phoenix.

Comment: OK, but if say I have a user that is closer to a Louisville server than a NYC server. Wouldn't it return America/Louisville instead of America/New York City ? That's what's bugging me.

Comment: @Jack why do you really want to know the user's time zone? If you deal with everything as a timestamp on your server, timezone is irrelevant; leave knowing the correct time zone up to the user.

Comment: OK, this is borderline ridiculous, but I'm working on some test fixes with a co-worker. We have this issue where certain of our tests that we have to fix as part of this project fail because it's either 1 hour ahead or 1 hour behind depending on the location of the user.

This is not a front end customer facing issue, and is specifically a non-issue, we are batting our heads trying to fix.

My solution is to just call the default time zone, and set the test specifically for that time.

Comment: In terms of Java, you can call `TimeZone.setDefault(String)` so you can make the test independent from the system's timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in [this list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for the ones labelled "canonical".

The simple answer is that there is no "default". If all you have is a three-letter time zone ID, you should pick the Olsen ID which works best for your application.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simplified list of the current primary IANA/Olson time zone identifiers for the 50 United States, then (as of writing this in Feb 2018) they are as follows:

> `America/New_York` - Eastern Time
>   `America/Chicago` - Central Time
>   `America/Denver` - Mountain Time (except most of Arizona)
>   `America/Phoenix` - Mountain Time (most of Arizona)
>   `America/Los_Angeles` - Pacific Time
>   `America/Anchorage` - Most of Alaska
>   `America/Adak` - Alaska - Aleutian Islands
>   `Pacific/Honolulu` - Hawaii

Of course there are also many US territories not in this list.  Also keep in mind that even the US time zones have changed over time, and thus there are many others such as `America/Indiana/Indianapolis` that should be used if you're wanting historical accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Given your use of the tag `java` I suppose you're looking for a java-based solution:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class PrintTimeZones {
    public final static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] tz = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
        Arrays.stream(tz)
            .filter(elem -> elem.startsWith("US/"))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

This prints the US-only timezones. You might change the filter to `startsWith("America/")` which will return more results (including South America, Mexico and Kanada).

Comment: What I'm looking for is a specific default ID. I would prefer EST, CST, MST, PST, HHST, but apparently that's out.

But I'm afraid let's say a co-worker in VA. runs this instead of "America/New York" it will be America/Louisville or something like that. 

And that goes for other Time Zones as well.

Comment: Just watch out using startsWith, because Honolulu is "Pacific/Honolulu", not "America/...".

Comment: @JackParker The problem with the abbreviated codes is that there are duplicate ones, e.g. CST (Central Standard Time, Cuba Standard Time and China Standard Time). Most programming languages should provide a library to work with timezones, so it shouldn't matter if it is `America/New York`, `America/Louisville` or `US/Eastern` as long as all of them share the same daylight saving time rules.

Comment: @Lothar there are also more subtle problems. For example, Java considers "PST" as an alias for "America/Los_Angeles" (which observes daylight savings), but "EST" as an alias for "GMT+5" (which does not observe daylight savings).

Comment: OK, fantastic, Then I know what to do then.

Comment: @AndyTurner as an European, I couldn't care less ;-)

Comment: OK, then what about `TimeZone.getTimeZone("europe/Berlin")`? There's some subtle behaviour you might care about ;)